# Reusing context.WithTimeout in deferred function

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go, go-context

The below code snippet (reduced for brevity) from [MongoDB's Go quickstart blog post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-golang-mongodb-starting-and-setup) creates `context.WithTimeout` at the time of connecting with the database and reuses the same for the deferred `Disconnect` function, which I think is buggy.

```
func main() {
    client, _ := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("<ATLAS_URI_HERE>"))
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)

    _ = client.Connect(ctx)
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)
}
```

My train of thought-

`context.WithTimeout` sets a deadline in UNIX time at the point it is created.
So, passing it to `Connect` makes sense as we want to cancel the process of establishing the connection if it exceeds the time limit (ie, the derived UNIX time).

Now, passing the same `ctx` to the deferred `Disconnect`, which will most probably be called late in the future, will result in the `ctx`'s time being in the past. Meaning, it is already expired when the function starts executing. This is not what is expected and breaks the logic as- quoting the doc for `Disconnect`-

> If the context expires via cancellation,
> deadline, or timeout before the in use connections have returned, the in use
> connections will be closed, resulting in the failure of any in flight read
> or write operations.

Please tell me if and how I am wrong and/or missing something.

Comment: If you need different contexts for `Connect` and `Disconnect`, why are you using the same context?

Comment: I think we always need to use different `contexts.WithTimeout`s for  `Connect` and `Disconnect` as there is always going to be (significant) code/work to do between the connection and disconnection. This code is from a blog post from MongoDB with the problem I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes, which is why I asked why you are using the same context. It appears that this is just copied from a poor example which you are not intended to use verbatim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

In the example it is sufficient because the example just connects to the database, performs some example operation (e.g. lists databases), then `main()` ends, so running the deferred disconnect with the same context will cause no trouble (the example will/should run well under 10 seconds).

In "real-world" applications this won't be the case of course. So you will likely not use the same context for connecting and disconnecting (unless that context has no timeout).